# Rails ActionView::TemplateError (shop_url failed to generate from 

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this but I have not changed any of these codes. And my development environment works perfectly fine. This happens in production.

This happen when there is matching entries. When there is no matching entries, it's ok (obviously!).

```
Processing ShopsController#index (for 118.100.246.177 at 2010-11-25 01:46:48) [GET]
  Parameters: {"country"=>"France", "action"=>"index", "filter"=>"on", "order"=>"rating_descend", "type"=>"places", "controller"=>"shops", "keyword"=>""}
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering shops/index

ActionView::TemplateError (shop_url failed to generate from {:type=>"places", :action=>"show", :controller=>"shops"}, expected: {:controller=>"shops", :action=>"show"}, diff: {:type=>"places"}) on line #50 of app/views/shops/index.html.erb:
47: 
48:               <% @shops.each do |shop| %>
49:                 <div id="<%= dom_id(shop) %>" class="item">
50:                   <a href="<%= shop_path(shop, :type => @type) %>">
51:                     <% if !shop.photos.blank? %>
52:                       <%= image_tag(shop.photos.last.url(:thumb), :class => 'thumbnail') %>
53:                     <% else %>

    facebooker (1.0.75) lib/facebooker/rails/facebook_url_rewriting.rb:53:in `rewrite_url'
    facebooker (1.0.75) lib/facebooker.rb:200:in `request_for_canvas'
    facebooker (1.0.75) lib/facebooker/rails/facebook_url_rewriting.rb:52:in `rewrite_url'
    (eval):17:in `shop_path'
    app/views/shops/index.html.erb:50
    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thinking-sphinx-1.3.20/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:137:in `each'
    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thinking-sphinx-1.3.20/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:137:in `send'
    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thinking-sphinx-1.3.20/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:137:in `method_missing'
    app/views/shops/index.html.erb:48
    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-oauth-1.0.8/lib/oauth_callback_filter.rb:10:in `call'
    /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-oauth-1.0.8/lib/oauth_callback_filter.rb:10:in `call'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:92:in `process_request'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:207:in `main_loop'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:441:in `start_request_handler'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:381:in `handle_spawn_application'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:252:in `safe_fork'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:377:in `handle_spawn_application'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:222:in `start'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rails_application'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:247:in `spawn_rails_application'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rails_application'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:145:in `spawn_application'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:278:in `handle_spawn_application'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
    passenger (2.2.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'

Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering errors/500.html.erb (500)
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
```

When my `type` is others like `garages`, `malls`, etc., they all worked perfectly well. I even rebuilt my Thinking Sphinx index.

**UPDATE**
Turns out MySQL ID autoincrement from 1, 2, 3... I deleted the 1, 2, 3 entry and replace the ID with 200000, 200001, 200002 and it gave me problem. Didn't know Rails was so strict.

Comment: Do you have a `shop` object that hasn't yet been saved? i.e. is this inside a nested resource where you're doing `something.shops.build` in the controller action?

Comment: Alternatively, do you have a custom `to_param` method on the `Shop` class and does one of the shops contain a period (.) in its `to_param` version?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty clear from the error message. The :type => `"places"` is causing you grief. You may need to pin the `"?type=places` onto the end of the generated URL if that's what you really intend to pass to the controller.

Comment: I think it's a little more than this... possibly a `shop` object that hasn't yet been saved.

Comment: That's possible. I didn't see anything in the params hash that implied a nested resource, but I could have missed something. OP: Did you write a test for that route?

Comment: The error indeed is clearly indicating this. Either use a different named/nested route, or attach it as a parameter.