# Entry created with old model gave problem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an entry that was created very long time ago, and many changes have been made ever since, I can't totally recall all the changes.

The thing is, ever since then, I can't delete that old entry from database. If I delete it, whenever any search result that matches it, the app can't find that entry and would return unrelated errors.

Even if I don't delete it, I change its ID, it would still give problem.

I know this is weird, but it happened to my developer too. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: This is totally incomprehensible: 1) you say you can't delete it, but 2) you say you delete it and then you can't find it anymore. That sounds like a very succesfull deletion to me. Changing ID's in a database should be ok, and could only succeed if there are no foreign-key constraints. So if changing the ID works, there is no impact.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really vague description.

By 'entry' do you mean a record in the database?

I'd like to know more about "If I delete it, whenever any search result that matches it, the app can't find that entry ".  What do you mean 'search'?  A simple active record find?  Some other kind of indexed search like ferret, sphinx, etc?

What are the 'unrelated errors'?

What do you mean 'it happened to your developer too'?  Are you not a developer?

Provide some actual details of the problem rather than a vague description please.

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270067/rails-actionviewtemplateerror-shop-url-failed-to-generate-from

Comment: The linked question seems totally unrelated to this question.